# Remove "set of xml tag" using sed

Tags: xml, sed

I have huge xml file. i want to match particular string and delete whole related tag example xml

```
<server>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</server>
```

In this xml i want to match 3 things `<server>..<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>....</server>`. if it matches 3 thing delete whole thing. I tried sed command below.

```
sed -i '/server/,/server/ d' web1.xml
```

So in this thing sever to sever whole thing will be delete. but i want match 3rd thing also `default` like below command

```
sed -i '/server/,/webnav/,/server/ d' web1.xml
```

this command not working but i want to like this

Comment: Use `xml` aware tools and not `sed`

Comment: @Inian what is this xml tool. I am not aware of this.

Comment: check about http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/source.php

Comment: This is use for automation purpose to run all server so i can't install this tool. Any otherway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in your comments, sed is not the right tool for parsing xml.

That being said, if you have no choice you can try this one (at your own risk):

```
sed '/<server>/{:a;/<\/server>/!{N;ba;}};/<servlet-name>default<\/servlet-name>/d;' web1.xml
```

Lines between `<server>` and `</server>` are merged and then deleted if  the string `<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>` is found.

**Explanation:**

- `/<server>/`: if `<server>` is found
- `:a`: label `a` for loop to come
- `/<\/server>/!`: if `</server>` is not found:
- `N`: appends next line to pattern space
- `ba`: loops to `:a` label
- `/<servlet-name>default<\/servlet-name>/`: when loop ends, search for string  `<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>` in pattern space. And if found:
- `d`: clean the pattern space (ie deletes all from `<server>` to `</server>`

Comment: Thanks for your code this code is working fine. I am new in sed, could you explain this code?

Comment: if some times server or server-mapping also come that time i tried edit your code like this `/<(server|server-mapping)>/{:a;/<\/(server|server-mapping)>/!{N;ba;}}..` but it's not working help me

Comment: You must escape brackets and pipes: `/<\(server\|server-mapping\)>/`